# spring boot aggregation is not giving desired results

Tags: java, spring-boot, grouping

I am facing an issue doing aggregation. Here is my json:

```
{
"criteria": {
    "partyType": "Person",
    "facets": [
        "branchId", "partType"....
        ]
}
```

}

match criteria is "partyType": "Person" and I want to aggregate on one or more fields:

```
"facets": [
        "branchId", "partType"....
        ]
```

Here is my BaseDAO code:

```
private <T> List<T> getAggregateResults(List<String> facets)
{
    String strFacets = StringUtils.join(facets, ',');
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("_id.partyType").is("Person")), 
        project(strFacets).and("totalCount"),
        group(strFacets).count().as("totalCount"))
            .withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());

    AggregationResults<T> groupResults = (AggregationResults<T>) mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        agg,
        this.getCollectionName(), FacetResults.class);

    return groupResults.getMappedResults();
}
```

The output looks like the following when grouping is performed on "branchId":

```
"aggResults"     (id=157)   
[0...99]    
    [0] FacetResults  (id=168)  
    [1] FacetResults  (id=169)  
        Id  null    
        totalCount  8   
    [2] FacetResults  (id=170)
```

If you notice, Id is coming as null, it should be a branch Id. If I group on 2 fields, it gives me on i item in output as:
Id  null
totalCount  1830000

My facetResults class is as follows:

```
public class FacetResults

    {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String Id;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private long totalCount;
}
```

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I resolved the issue for single field grouping...updated facetResults field name from Id to _id {

private String _id;                  I still have an issue. I want to group on more than one field. I am getting field names as arraylist. How can I pass them in groupOperation?